# Oscillating a circuit on and off repeatedly to save water

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, power-electronics, oscillation

I am using a foamer unit (a device that intermittently drops a blob of foam behind a moving vehicle to mark its path). The problem is that it's dropping about 10 x more foam than I really need, hence using lots of unnecessary water.

I thus want to increase the time between each intermittent foam drop. I know nothing about electronics so want to use this as a first project! At the moment the foam has an on-off switch. I am thinking that the simplest way to reduce the foam used would be to add something that breaks the connection, for say 10 seconds every 5 seconds (when the switch is ON). So that when you flick the switch ON the foam unit will power on for 5 seconds then off for 10 then on for 5 etc etc etc. I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to do this (or other solutions to save water!).

I know I could do this with an Arduino & a relay but I don't want to have to use batteries to power the Arduino. (unless there's another way to power it?)

Sorry if this is a basic question! I have no electronics background but saving the wasted water would really be good.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the unit inside a vehicle ? Use vehicle power / battery to power your arduino.

Comment: It seems to be a trivial project, but, if you _"know nothing about electronics"_, and _"have no electronics background"_, this is not a good option for a first project. Maybe a better solution would be to adjust the equipment to increase the time between the releasing of blobs. It could be better hiring a professional for building a device, or for helping / advising you. The users in EE.SE can provide you effective help for specific design / build questions, but **this is not the kind site** where you write the specification of a device or circuit, hoping that someone will design it for you.